# Does anyone know how to add a scrubber to the seekbar in jPlayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I built a custom skin for jPlayer, and I am using it to play multiple instances of audio players on a page.  I started with the theme Blue Monday and made my edits; however, I really want a scrubber/dragger as well as the seekbar.

My seekbar works great and follows, but I can't figure out how to add a scrubber to the player.  Does anyone know how to build this?

I thought about building this by binding a div to the seeking event, calculated by the percentage in an event loop, but it would have to be a draggable object, also a touch object and then it wouldn't work in flash anyway... so.

Maybe this is a skinnable feature...?  Thanks in advance.